# Decimal number to hexadecimal string

Tags: rust

Does Rust have a set of functions that make converting a decimal integer to a hexadecimal string easy? I have no trouble converting a string to an integer, but I can't seem to figure out the opposite. Currently what I have does not work (and may be a bit of an abomination)

**Editor's note** - this code predates Rust 1.0 and no longer compiles.

```
pub fn dec_to_hex_str(num: uint) -> String {
    let mut result_string = String::from_str("");
    let mut i = num;
    while i / 16 > 0 {
        result_string.push_str(String::from_char(1, from_digit(i / 16, 16).unwrap()).as_slice());
        i = i / 16;
    }
    result_string.push_str(String::from_char(1, from_digit(255 - i * 16, 16).unwrap()).as_slice());

    result_string
}
```

Am I on the right track, or am I overthinking this whole thing?

Comment: Incidentally, `string.push_str(String::from_char(1, char).as_slice())` is impressively inefficient; to do something like that, `string.push_char(char)` is what you should do.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan thanks for the pointer, I'm very new to rust coming from c++ and know some of the concepts i'm using are bad.

Answer (score 91):

You’re overthinking the whole thing.

```
assert_eq!(format!("{:x}", 42), "2a");
assert_eq!(format!("{:X}", 42), "2A");
```

That’s from [`std::fmt::LowerHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.LowerHex.html) and [`std::fmt::UpperHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.UpperHex.html), respectively. See also [a search of the documentation for "hex"](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=hex).

Comment: @10cls: `as_slice` was just for getting the `&str` out of the `String` so you could compare it with a string slice. `assert_eq!` has changed now so that you don’t even need `&` or `&*` as in `&*format!(…)`.