# How to pass a variable as a string literal in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am using a macro [`hex!`](https://docs.rs/hex-literal/0.2.1/hex_literal/index.html) that accepts only string literals.
 I have a value returned from a function and stored in a variable. I cannot hard-code the values and call this function. So, how can I call the `hex!` macro with a variable?

This is my working code:

```
let account: AccountId32 = hex_literal::hex!["d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"].into();
```

and this is the code where I am facing the error:

```
let account_id = "d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d";
let account: AccountId32 = hex_literal::hex!(&account_id).into();
```

The error is:

```
error: proc-macro derive panicked
  --> src/examples/example_substratekitties.rs:49:32
   |
49 |     let account: AccountId32 = hex_literal::hex!(&account_id).into();
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: message: expected one string literal
   = note: this warning originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

All the examples of the `hex!` macro only demonstrate it with string literals.

Comment: I'm not certain the `&` is even necessary here.

Comment: removed it, still the same error.

Comment: [What is the difference between macros and functions in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29871967/155423)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Convert a hex string to a number runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot. It is *literally* impossible. A literal is something where the value is written verbatim in the source code of the program.

Don't use that macro because it doesn't do what you want (emphasis mine):

> This crate provides `hex!` macro for converting hexadecimal string literal to byte array **at compile time**.

Perhaps you want the [hex crate](https://docs.rs/hex/0.4.2/hex/)?

See also:

- [What is the difference between literals and non-literals, other than the fact that non-literals go into the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48411196/155423)
- [What does the word "literal" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/485119/155423)
- [How can I convert a hex string to a u8 slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52987181/155423)
- [Converting a hexadecimal string to a decimal integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32381414/155423)
- [Decimal number to hexadecimal string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25007328/155423)
- [How to convert hex string to a float in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43704630/155423)
- [How do I convert a string to hex in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27492969/155423)
- [Show u8 slice in hex representation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27650312/155423)